# Fetching Initials of the Commentator in the Wordpress Website

Tags: php, functions, comments, comment-form

```
function getInitials($str) {
    $words = explode(" ", $str);
    $initials = null;
    foreach ($words as $w) {
         $initials .= $w[0];
    }
    return $initials; //DT
}

echo $str = getInitials('Donald Trump');
```

## Objective →

#
I want to fetch the initials of the commentator's name.

Suppose the commentators' name is Donald Trump then I should get →

> DT

I have tried something, but I guess that this is not a complete one and won't work fully.

can someone help me in making this edifice an effective version?

Comment: Its working fine... did you had cases thats its break?

Comment: How do you get the comments in the template comments.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is function that return you the comment author initials by the comment id

```
function get_comment_author_initials($comment_id) {
    $author = get_comment_author($comment_id);
    $words = explode(" ", $author);
    $initials = null;
    foreach ($words as $w) {
        $split = mb_str_split($w); // to cover unicode char
        $initials .= $split[0];
    }
    return $initials;
}

function mb_str_split( $string ) {
    return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string );
}
```

And you can use it in your code like this

```
<div class="class2">
    <?php echo get_comment_author_initials($comment->comment_ID); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is this CM?

Comment: Edit your question add the code of the CM and where did you put it in... the whole thing.

Comment: @TheWPNovice Check the code now